# python-docx how can i save docx to the specific path?

Tags: python, python-docx

I use the sample from python-docx and after I run the code I cannot find where is the docx file can I point specific path I want to add?

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches

document = Document('C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\python test\update_test\\test.docx')

document.add_heading('Document Title', 0)

p = document.add_paragraph('A plain paragraph having some ')
p.add_run('bold').bold = True
p.add_run(' and some ')
p.add_run('italic.').italic = True

document.add_heading('Heading, level 1', level=1)
document.add_paragraph('Intense quote', style='Intense Quote')

document.add_paragraph(
    'first item in unordered list', style='List Bullet'
)
document.add_paragraph(
    'first item in ordered list', style='List Number'
)

filename='test.docx'


filepath=r'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\python test\update_test'+filename

document.add_page_break()

document.save(filepath)
```

Comment: is 'update_test' a folder? if so you need another "\" after, in the `filepath` varibale. Also, it's probably more beneficial to use the `os` module to complete this.

Comment: thanks reply, yes update_test is a folder name  and I tried add "\" but still not work

Comment: I suggest you use `filepath = os.path.join(r'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\python test\update_test', filename)` rather than string concatenation, it deals with adding backslashes automatically.

Comment: Are you sure the icon on the desktop is not just hiding somewhere? Suggest you open an explorer window for the desktop and sort by date.

Comment: Thanks Martin It is worked for me now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
document.save('C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\python test\\update_test\\' + 'test.docx')
```

Comment: While a good answer, it's usually a good idea to toss in an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

What wasn't explained here is that Python does not read a `filepath` with single backslashes. Usually, it reads it as double backslashes or single forward slashes.
Your original method does work if you do this:

```
filePath = 'test2.docx'
doc.save('J:/drive/testFolder/CloudExile/' + filePath)
```

or

```
doc.save('J:\\drive\\testFolder\\CloudExile\\' + filePath)
```

I hope that helps give more insight to anyone looking at this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please format your code properly, [click here to learn how](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).